# Serving images from NGINX

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, web-deployment, nginx-reverse-proxy

I hosted a website on my vps with NGINX where my backend(in Node.js) is in '/root/backend/MyApp' directory. And my frontend(in React.js) is served from '/var/www/app/client' which contains my build files including index.html. I am storing profile image of user via '/api/upload/profileimage' endpoint and the image gets uploaded in '/root/backend/MyApp/uploads/profileImages' directory using 'Multer'. How do configure nginx so that I can serve these uploaded images via a url in frontend?
Right now my server configuration looks like:

```
server {
  server_name {my domain name};

  location / {
    root /var/www/app/client;
    index index.html index.htm;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://185.201.8.18:8800;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
server {
  server_name {my domain name};

  location / {
    root /var/www/app/client;
    index index.html index.htm;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://185.201.8.18:8800;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location /profileimages/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias /root/backend/MyApp/uploads/profileImages/;
  }
}
```

You should be able to access the images: yourwebsite.com/profileimages/

Comment: Hey! I am getting 403 forbidden on trying to request website.com/profileImages/image.png. Can you please help me fix this?

Comment: Did you restart nginx? remember that it is case sensitive, profileImages is different from profileimages.

Comment: Its working now! Thanks! Actually I didn't had read permissions on the directory for nginx user that was creating the issue!